# Passar letra maiúsculas para minúsculas

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable, rich-faces

Tenho um componente do richfaces datatable que retorna um registro do banco e esse registro vem com letras maiúsculas.

Exemplo: `PAULO FERNANDES DA SILVA`.

Teria algo que eu pudesse fazer para editar esse nome com CSS para `Paulo Fernandes Da Silva` para ser mostrado no datatable?

Ps.: Estou usando HTML4.

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade é converter o nome para minúsculas antes de inserir no HTML, e depois estilizar com `text-transform: capitalize`;

```js
var nome = 'PAULO FERNANDES DA SILVA';

document.getElementById('nome').innerHTML = nome.toLowerCase();
```

```css
#nome {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p id="nome"></p> <!-- Paulo Fernandes Da Silva -->
```

Comment: variável nome está estática. Mas ela vem do banco, como eu posso fazer para ele receber esse dado da base com javascript?

Comment: aí não sei. Você colocou a tag javascript, achei que já estava recebendo o dado por ele.